# HTML table fetching data

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I have created a website using app script wherein I have a table that displays data from the spreadsheet. It's all good but when a new data is added on the sheet I need to refresh the whole page in order for the new data to appear on the website, also I'm seeing a pop-up notification or error that says

> DataTables warning: table id=data-table6 - Requested unknown parameter
> '7' for row 9, column 7. For more information about this error, please
> see http://datatables.net/tn/4

What I want is when a new data is added I won't need to refresh the whole page and the data in the table will change it's background color to red. I'm still new to coding. Can someone help me?

Here's the code on my Code.gs

```
 function getData1(){
 var spreadSheetId = "mySpreadsheetId"; //spreadsheet ID
 var dataRange     = "Data!A2:N"; //CHANGE

 var range   = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId,dataRange);
 var values  = range.values;
 Logger.log(values);
 return values;
 }
```

```js
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData1();
  setInterval(function showData(dataArray){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
        columns: [
          {"title":"Task"},
          {"title":"Pending"},
          {"title":"Completed"},
          {"title":"Link",
          "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            if(type === 'display'){
              data = '<a href="' + data + '" target="_blank">' + data + '</a>';
            }
            return data;
          }
        }
        ]
      }, 1000 );
    });
  })
```

```css
#datatable {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

#datatable td,
#data-table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#datatable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#datatable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#datatable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
```

Comment: if you want to get data from the server without refreshing your page you either need to do some kind of push notification like Signal R or you need to do some kind of scheduled polling with setinterval and an ajax call

Comment: I'm not really good at coding could you provide me a sample? :<